# how can i convert time '08:60:02' to '09:00:02' using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a special requirement where need to sum time columns, but for few      record sum time is coming '08:60:02' so i need to get it as '09:00:02'. I tried to convert it to seconds first and then convert back to h:m:s but it's giving null as result.

Comment: The harish answer ? Could you please explain ?

Comment: Look Your question: "how can i convert time '08:60:02' to '09:00:02' using php?" ... You asked PHP solution, but got a wrong SQL query. It's confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try mysql functions  like 
SELECT round((SUM((08:60:02))/60)/100, 1);

Answer (score 5):

```
$a = date_create_from_format("H:i:s", "08:60:02");
echo $a->format("H:i:s");
```

shows

`09:00:02`